# Need to automate a script to search and replace HEX to DEC within XML files

Tags: xml, excel, batch-file, powershell

In short, we have an Access Control server (A) that exports Card Holders into an XML file every minute.

This file needs to be imported into another Access Control server (B).

The XML file that Server (A) exports has all the card numbers in HEX format like this; `DEC61810000000`

I know how to achieve the conversion in Excel, here is an example;

1. I need to replace the first 8 characters, ignoring the last six zeros.
2. I need to invert the HEX from this `DEC61810` to this `1018C6DE` (notice how the numbers are kept in pairs but switched locations).

   - The code to do this in Excel is as follows; `=CONCATENATE(MID(C5,7,2),MID(C5,5,2),MID(C5,3,2),LEFT(C5,2))`
3. Now that the last six digits are stripped, and the HEX is inverted, I need to convert `1018C6DE` to DEC, which comes out to `270059230`

   - The code to do this in Excel is as follows;
     `=HEX2DEC(D5)`

So my problem is that I don't know how to automate this procedure and I don't know how to implement this against an XML file.

The environment is MS Windows 7 / Windows 2008, I don't mind how it is implemented, be it power shell ,FART.exe or any other search & replace tool.

Thanks,
Steve

### -----------------------------------------------------

Thanks everyone for your help. I was able to satisfy that particular requirement with the java-script.

Now it gets more interesting. A new requirement is asking to be able to reverse the process where data is flowing from Server (B) to Server (A). So now I need to reverse the order.

It will start with an XML file which will have the DEC version, and the converted file will need to have the HEX format with the 000000 at the end.

The output file can be a plain .txt file with the following format; (the end ;3;1 is always the same)

```
1;One;TestOne;E4583A4F000000;3;1
2;Two;TestTwo;9B2EB93F000000;3;1
```

Here is a sample XML with two (2) card holder entries.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<CrossFire culture-info="en-US" platform-version="0.0.640.0024" product-version="0.0.640.0025">
  <SoftwareHouse.NextGen.Common.SecurityObjects.Personnel ImportMode="Default">
    <FirstName>One</FirstName>
    <LastName>OneTest</LastName>
    <SoftwareHouse.NextGen.Common.SecurityObjects.PersonnelClearancePair ImportMode="Default">
      <ClearanceKey>Clearance_1 [[Default]]</ClearanceKey>
      <PersonnelID>5000</PersonnelID>
    </SoftwareHouse.NextGen.Common.SecurityObjects.PersonnelClearancePair>
    <SoftwareHouse.NextGen.Common.SecurityObjects.Credential ImportMode="Default">
      <CardNumber>1329223908</CardNumber>
      <Disabled>False</Disabled>
    </SoftwareHouse.NextGen.Common.SecurityObjects.Credential>
  </SoftwareHouse.NextGen.Common.SecurityObjects.Personnel>
  <SoftwareHouse.NextGen.Common.SecurityObjects.Personnel ImportMode="Default">
    <FirstName>Two</FirstName>
    <LastName>TwoTest</LastName>
    <SoftwareHouse.NextGen.Common.SecurityObjects.PersonnelClearancePair ImportMode="Default">
      <ClearanceKey>Clearance_1 [[Default]]</ClearanceKey>
      <PersonnelID>5001</PersonnelID>
    </SoftwareHouse.NextGen.Common.SecurityObjects.PersonnelClearancePair>
    <SoftwareHouse.NextGen.Common.SecurityObjects.Credential ImportMode="Default">
      <CardNumber>1069100699</CardNumber>
      <Disabled>False</Disabled>
    </SoftwareHouse.NextGen.Common.SecurityObjects.Credential>
  </SoftwareHouse.NextGen.Common.SecurityObjects.Personnel>
</CrossFire>
```

Comment: Is speed a factor?  A sample file on dropbox etc would allow us to examine the layout.

Comment: Speed is a factor, however these XML files will normally only have like 10 or so Card Holder records in them, so I don't see this as being very intense. I will post a sample file tomorrow when I get to the office...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a powershell solution:

```
function Get-AccessControlDecimal
{
    param
    (
        [string]$AccessControlHex
    )

    # create an array to store the results
    $ac2=@()

    # loop around each pair of values adding to new array
    for($i=0; $i -lt $AccessControlHex.length; $i+=2){
        $ac2+=$AccessControlHex[($i)..($i+1)] -join ""
    }
    # Reverse the order of the array
    [array]::Reverse($ac2)

    # Join the array back together
    $ac2 = $ac2 -join ""

    # convert to decimal
    [Convert]::ToInt32($ac2,16)
}

Get-AccessControlDecimal("DEC61810000000")
```

---

**Update 1**

Here's a complete solution for your new requirements, I have provided a function to go to and from hex and validated them in the loop.

```
# Read xml, would normally use get-content
# [xml]$xml = Get-Content -Path $filename
[xml]$xml = @"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<CrossFire culture-info="en-US" platform-version="0.0.640.0024" product-version="0.0.640.0025">
  <SoftwareHouse.NextGen.Common.SecurityObjects.Personnel ImportMode="Default">
    <FirstName>One</FirstName>
    <LastName>OneTest</LastName>
    <SoftwareHouse.NextGen.Common.SecurityObjects.PersonnelClearancePair ImportMode="Default">
      <ClearanceKey>Clearance_1 [[Default]]</ClearanceKey>
      <PersonnelID>5000</PersonnelID>
    </SoftwareHouse.NextGen.Common.SecurityObjects.PersonnelClearancePair>
    <SoftwareHouse.NextGen.Common.SecurityObjects.Credential ImportMode="Default">
      <CardNumber>1329223908</CardNumber>
      <Disabled>False</Disabled>
    </SoftwareHouse.NextGen.Common.SecurityObjects.Credential>
  </SoftwareHouse.NextGen.Common.SecurityObjects.Personnel>
  <SoftwareHouse.NextGen.Common.SecurityObjects.Personnel ImportMode="Default">
    <FirstName>Two</FirstName>
    <LastName>TwoTest</LastName>
    <SoftwareHouse.NextGen.Common.SecurityObjects.PersonnelClearancePair ImportMode="Default">
      <ClearanceKey>Clearance_1 [[Default]]</ClearanceKey>
      <PersonnelID>5001</PersonnelID>
    </SoftwareHouse.NextGen.Common.SecurityObjects.PersonnelClearancePair>
    <SoftwareHouse.NextGen.Common.SecurityObjects.Credential ImportMode="Default">
      <CardNumber>1069100699</CardNumber>
      <Disabled>False</Disabled>
    </SoftwareHouse.NextGen.Common.SecurityObjects.Credential>
  </SoftwareHouse.NextGen.Common.SecurityObjects.Personnel>
</CrossFire>
"@

function Get-ReversedArrary
{
    param
    (
        $accessControlCard
    )

    # create an array to store the results
    $result=@()

    # loop around each pair of values adding to new array
    for($i=0; $i -lt $accessControlCard.length; $i+=2){
        $result+=$accessControlCard[($i)..($i+1)] -join ""
    }
    # Reverse the order of the array
    [array]::Reverse($result)

    # Join the array back together
    $result -join ""
}

function Get-AccessControlDecimal
{
    param
    (
        [string]$AccessControlHex
    )

    $reversed = Get-ReversedArrary($AccessControlHex)

    # convert to decimal
    [Convert]::ToInt32($reversed,16)
}

function Get-AccessControlHex
{
    param
    (
        [string]$AccessControlDecimal
    )

    # convert to Hex
    $AccessControlHex = [Convert]::ToString($AccessControlDecimal,16)
    $AccessControlHex = Get-ReversedArrary($AccessControlHex) 
    $AccessControlHex += "000000"
    $AccessControlHex 
}

# loop around xml
$i = 0
$crossfire = @()
$xml.CrossFire."SoftwareHouse.NextGen.Common.SecurityObjects.Personnel" | %{
    $i++

    # 
    $cardNumber = $_."SoftwareHouse.NextGen.Common.SecurityObjects.Credential".CardNUmber
    $cardNumberHex = Get-AccessControlHex($cardNumber)
    $cardNumberDec = Get-AccessControlDecimal($cardNumberHex)

    # Just for proving
    if ($cardNumber -ne $cardNumberDec)
    {
        Write-Error "Conversion to from hex failed!"
    }

    $o = @{
        Id              = $i
        Firstname       = $_.FirstName
        LastName        = $_.LastName
        CardNumberHex   = $cardNumberHex
        Three           = 3
        One             = 1
    }
    $crossfire += New-Object PSObject -Property $o
}

# convert to csv, remove headers and quotes
$crossfire | select Id, FirstName, LastName, CardNUmberHex, Three, One | `
    ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation | select -skip 1 | % {$_.Replace('"','')}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked also, but it assumes only one card number, I attached to my question a sample of an XML file that has two card holders. Also I now need to reverse the process.

Comment: Thanks, I removed all the XML code and typed this, [xml]$xml = Get-Content -path c:\apps\file*.xml and when I run this script as such .\test.ps1 > c:\apps\text.txt I get the txt file with the correct output.

Comment: I tried the script as stated above when there was more than 1 xml file within the c:\apps folder it produced an error

Comment: I see you are new to StackOverflow, this is now you're 3rd requirement introduced to this question.  You have 3 very good answers to your original question and follow up requirement.  You'll find that with StackOverflow the more effort put in to questions the more you'll get out.  My particular answer shows how to work with one file, I cannot guess how you implemented your multiple file solution nor what the error your experiencing.  It may now be appropriate to start a new question possibly entitled: "Reading multiple XML files produces X error".

Comment: Yes I am new to StackOverflow :) I marked your answer as it is native to Windows, not having to install any other components.

Comment: Is there a way to contact you?

Comment: @user3404205 If you have a follow up question, just post it on StackOverflow, you'll find many people will be willing to help you, me included.

Comment: I posted an update to this question here http://stackoverflow.com/q/22439293/3404205. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

How about using javascript?

This will find every 8 digit HEX words followed by 6 zeros in the input form, eliminate 6 zeros, change order and convert to decimal number.

```
<html>
    <script>
        function convert() {
            var input = document.getElementById("input-text");

            var words = input.value.split(/[ \t\n]/);
            var reg = new RegExp("[a-fA-F0-9]{8}000000");
            for (var i=0;i<words.length; i++) {
                var word = words[i];
                if(word.match(reg)) {
                    // 8 digits HEX number with 6 zeros
                    var v1,v2,v3,v4
                    v1 = word.substr(0,2);
                    v2 = word.substr(2,2);
                    v3 = word.substr(4,2);
                    v4 = word.substr(6,2);
                    word = v4+v3+v2+v1;
                    words[i] = ""+parseInt(word, 16)
                } else {
                }
            }

            var output = "";
            for (var i=0; i<words.length; i++) {
                output = output + words[i]+" ";
            }
            document.getElementById("output-text").value = output;
        }
</script>
<body>
    <textarea id="input-text"></textarea><br>
    <input value="convert" type="button" onclick="convert();"></input><br>
    <textarea id="output-text"></textarea><br>
</body>

</html>
```

Or install node.js from http://nodejs.org/

And create hex2dec.js file

```
function convert(input) {
    var words = input.split(/[ \t\n]/);
    var reg = new RegExp("[a-fA-F0-9]{8}000000");
    for (var i=0;i<words.length; i++) {
        var word = words[i];
        if(word.match(reg)) {
            // 8 digits HEX number with 6 zeros
            var v1,v2,v3,v4
            v1 = word.substr(0,2);
            v2 = word.substr(2,2);
            v3 = word.substr(4,2);
            v4 = word.substr(6,2);
            word = v4+v3+v2+v1;
            words[i] = ""+parseInt(word, 16)
        } else {
        }
    }

    var output = "";
    for (var i=0; i<words.length; i++) {
        output = output + words[i]+" ";
    }
    console.log(output);
}

process.stdin.on('readable', function(chunk) {
    var input = process.stdin.read();
    if (input !== null) {
        convert(""+input);
    }
});
```

node hex2dec.js < inputfile > outputfile

---

For your second request, you need an xml parser

You can easily install xml parser for node.js from

https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js

or enter

npm install xml2js

then make dec2hex.js file as following.

```
var xml2js = require('xml2js');

var parser = new xml2js.Parser();

process.stdin.on('readable', function(chunk) {
    var input = process.stdin.read();
    if (input !== null) {
        parser.parseString(""+input, function(err,result){
            //Extract the value from the data element
           var arr = (result.CrossFire["SoftwareHouse.NextGen.Common.SecurityObjects.Personnel"]);
           for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
               var node = arr[i];
               var firstName = node.FirstName[0];
               var lastName = node.LastName[0];
               var cardNumber = node["SoftwareHouse.NextGen.Common.SecurityObjects.Credential"][0].CardNumber[0];

               var word = parseInt(cardNumber).toString(16);
               var v1,v2,v3,v4
               v1 = word.substr(0,2);
               v2 = word.substr(2,2);
               v3 = word.substr(4,2);
               v4 = word.substr(6,2);
               word = v4+v3+v2+v1+"000000";
               word = word.toUpperCase();

               console.log((i+1)+";"+firstName+";"+lastName+";"+word+";3;1");
           }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As I am not familiar with java much, where do I declare in the script to look for the XML file that need the search & replace? I would want it to look at any XML file in a directory, i.e. c:\MyFiles\CARDS*.xml

Comment: Also, how would I invoke this to run on a schedule?

Comment: Just make an .HTML file and open it with web browser, paste content of your xml file into the first form. If you have to handle many files, then I recommend you to install node.js and use my second solution.

Comment: Thanks, the second solution worked. I also got a new requirement to reverse the order of the process, see my edit to my question. I also posted a sample of an XML file with two card holders.

Comment: Thanks, I ran this from windows command line, node dec2hex.js C:\File1.xml > c:\file1.txt and I get a new file c:\file1.txt but it is blank.

Comment: You should do node dec2hex.js < c:\File1.xml because the script reads from stdin.

Answer (score 1):

When a 32-bits hex number is converted to decimal there are two possible solutions: if the high-order bit is a sign bit (signed number), the result is between -2147483648 and 2147483647; otherwise, when the high-order bit is part of the number (unsigned number) the result is between 0 and 4294967295. The Batch code below assume the first case:

```
@echo off
set input=%1
echo Input: %input%
set /A output=0x%input:~6,2%%input:~4,2%%input:~2,2%%input:~0,2%
echo Output: %output%
```

Output example:

```
C:\> test DEC61810000000
Input: DEC61810000000
Output: 270059230
```

Previous code may be modified in order to convert an unsigned number, if needed.

If you show us the format of your .XML file, perhaps we may develop a Batch file that process it as required.

---

**EDIT**: *Solution for the new request added*

The Batch file below solve your second request, that is, it takes your xml sample file and produce the requested output:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set hexa=0123456789ABCDEF

set i=0
for /F "tokens=2,3 delims=<>" %%a in (input.txt) do (
   if "%%a" equ "FirstName" (
      set FirstName=%%b
   ) else if "%%a" equ "LastName" (
      set LastName=%%b
   ) else if "%%a" equ "CardNumber" (
      set CardNumber=%%b
      set "H="
      for /L %%i in (1,1,8) do (
         set /A "digit=CardNumber&0xF, CardNumber>>=4"
         for /F %%d in ("!digit!") do set "H=!H!!hexa:~%%d,1!"
      )
      set /A i+=1
      set CardHex=!H:~1,1!!H:~0,1!!H:~3,1!!H:~2,1!!H:~5,1!!H:~4,1!!H:~7,1!!H:~6,1!
      echo !i!;!FirstName!;!LastName!;!CardHex!000000;3;1
   )
)
```

Output example:

```
C:\> test
1;One;OneTest;E4583A4F000000;3;1
2;Two;TwoTest;9B2EB93F000000;3;1
```

Previous solution may be easily modified to process several *.XML files.

As I said before, in order to do the same thing with your first request, we need an example of the input file and the desired output...